# Converting a string value (array of char's) to a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

So basically this is what I want to do:

I have the decimal value 3 as such:

```
x=3
```

Now i get the binary format as such:

```
s = dec2bin(x,3)
s = 011
```

The format of s is a string (correct?).

Now I would like to convert this value to a matrix, in order to do matrix operations on it. As such:

```
A = [0 1 1]
```

But I cannot seem to get this right. I have tried both str2mat and cell2mat but no results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are 100% certain you will only be getting 0s and 1s, use:

```
a = '001';
b = double(a)-48;
```

(0 is 48 in ASCII)

Comment: Ah Fantastic! Yes, I'm using modulo 2 arithmetic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
>> cellfun(@str2num, cellstr(s'))'

ans =

     0     1     1
```

As you've noticed, MATLAB isn't that great for string manipulation. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can as well do that:

```
x=3;
binNumber = dec2bin(x,3);
A=sprintf('%s',binNumber) - '0';
```